# Select Multiple Images and Display in Multiple ImageView

Tags: android

I want to select 4 images from phone gallery and display them in 4 imageviews, so far below code is working fine by selecting 4 buttons individually.

Now i want to implement to select 4 images with 1 button and get them displayed in 4 imageview simulatenously, i am stuck here and have done many google search and found a solution by using getClipData below but after many trial and error still not working, can someone enlighthen me and appreicate your help.

```
  if(data.getClipData() != null) {
            int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount(); //evaluate the count before the for loop --- otherwise, the count is evaluated every loop.
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               // Uri filepath = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
            }
            //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
        }
    } else if(data.getData() != null) {
        String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
        //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
```

MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText t1,t2;
    // TextView tv_upload1;
    Button browse,browse_two,browse_three,browse_four,upload;
    ImageView img, img_two,img_three,img_four;
    Bitmap bitmap,bitmap_two,bitmap_three,bitmap_four;
    String encodeImageString,encodeImageString_two,encodeImageString_three,encodeImageString_four;
    private static final String url="http://example.com/fileupload.php";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button openActivityBtn = findViewById(R.id.openActivityBtn);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img_two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_two);
        img_three = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_three);
        img_four = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_four);

        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

        browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse);
        browse_two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse_two);
        browse_three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse_three);
        browse_four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse_four);

        browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dexter.withActivity(MainActivity.this)
                        .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Browse Image"), 1);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                                token.continuePermissionRequest();
                            }
                        }).check();
            }
        });

        //-----brose2
        browse_two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dexter.withActivity(MainActivity.this)
                        .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Browse Image"), 2);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                                token.continuePermissionRequest();
                            }
                        }).check();
            }
        });



        //-----browse3
        browse_three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dexter.withActivity(MainActivity.this)
                        .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Browse Image"), 3);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                                token.continuePermissionRequest();
                            }
                        }).check();
            }
        });



        //-----browse4
        browse_four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dexter.withActivity(MainActivity.this)
                        .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Browse Image"), 4);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                                token.continuePermissionRequest();
                            }
                        }).check();
            }
        });

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
                //    if (firstName.getText().toString().length() != 0);
                //     firstName.setError("Dealer name is required!");

                EditText fivecode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
                //    if (fivecode.getText().toString().length() != 12)
                //      fivecode.setError("12 digit 5+5 dealer code is required!");

                //--------progressbar start
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                //   mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.progress_detail));
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("UPLOAD STATUS");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Your photos are being uploaded...");
                mProgressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
                mProgressDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
                mProgressDialog.show();
                //---------progressbar end

                uploaddatatodb();
                return;
            }
        });

//-----------------view button
        openActivityBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ItemsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                //  mProgressDialog.show();
            }
        });
//-----------------view button

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            if(data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount(); //evaluate the count before the for loop --- otherwise, the count is evaluated every loop.
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                   // Uri filepath = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                }
                //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
            }
        } else if(data.getData() != null) {
            String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
            //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)


//               Uri filepath = data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imagePath);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                encodeBitmapImage(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
//start
        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri filepath = data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream_two = getContentResolver().openInputStream(filepath);//two
                bitmap_two = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream_two); //two
                img_two.setImageBitmap(bitmap_two);
                encodeBitmapImage_two(bitmap_two);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }//end

//start 3
        if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri filepath = data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream_three = getContentResolver().openInputStream(filepath);//two
                bitmap_three = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream_three); //two
                img_three.setImageBitmap(bitmap_three);
                encodeBitmapImage_three(bitmap_three);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }//end   3

//start 4
        if (requestCode == 4 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri filepath = data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream_four = getContentResolver().openInputStream(filepath);//two
                bitmap_four = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream_four); //two
                img_four.setImageBitmap(bitmap_four);
                encodeBitmapImage_four(bitmap_four);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }//end   4

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void encodeBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,30,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] bytesofimage=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        encodeImageString=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytesofimage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        //  encodeImageString_two=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytesofimage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    private void encodeBitmapImage_two(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,30,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] bytesofimage=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        //  encodeImageString=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytesofimage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        encodeImageString_two=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytesofimage, Base64.DEFAULT);

    }

    private void encodeBitmapImage_three(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,30,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] bytesofimage=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        //  encodeImageString=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytesofimage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        encodeImageString_three=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytesofimage, Base64.DEFAULT);

    }

    private void encodeBitmapImage_four(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,30,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] bytesofimage=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        //  encodeImageString=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytesofimage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        encodeImageString_four=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytesofimage, Base64.DEFAULT);

    }


    //-------------------refresh page after uploaded--------------
    public void checkStartOtherActivity(){
        //      Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //     i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //     startActivity(i);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void uploaddatatodb() {

        t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
        final String name = t1.getText().toString().trim();
        final String dsg = t2.getText().toString().trim();
        //   tv_upload1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_upload1);

//-----------------------------check imageview got inserted photos?----------
        if (img.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uploadimg).getConstantState()
                | img_two.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uploadimg_two).getConstantState()
                | img_three.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uploadimg_three).getConstantState()
                | img_four.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uploadimg_four).getConstantState()
        )
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"There are no photos inserted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                mProgressDialog.show();

                //     t1.setText("");
                //      t2.setText("");
                //      img.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploadimg);
                //      img_two.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploadimg_two);
                //      img_three.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploadimg_three);
                //      img_four.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploadimg_four);

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Photos uploaded successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //     img.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploadimg);
                //     img_two.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploadimg_two);
                //     img_three.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploadimg_three);
                //     img_four.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploadimg_four);

                //---------------------without refresh page-------------------
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
                startActivity(getIntent());
                overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please insert all photos",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("t1", name);
                map.put("t2", dsg);
                map.put("upload", encodeImageString);
                map.put("upload_two", encodeImageString_two);
                map.put("upload_three", encodeImageString_three);
                map.put("upload_four", encodeImageString_four);

                return map;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show onActivityResult for browse_two button.

Comment: Using getClipData is ok if the user selected multiple images. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: When I select the image with button 1 browse onclick, there are no images or responses. I modified onActivityRrsult, I think some code is not working here.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following way . I have used viewBinding in this project and have used the new activity contracts for getting images since startActivity is deprecated .The code is as follows .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     //Getting the binding 
    ActivityMainBinding binding;


    //Defining a contract and assiging it to imageView
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetMultipleContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<List<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(List<Uri> result) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                        binding.imgone.setImageURI(result.get(0));
                        binding.imgtwo.setImageURI(result.get(1));
                        binding.imgthree.setImageURI(result.get(2));
                        binding.imgfour.setImageURI(result.get(3));

                    }
                }
            });

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

     //Launching contract for getting images
        binding.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mGetMultipleContent.launch("image/*");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Use this xml layout  for the above code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgtwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgthree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgtwo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfour"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgthree" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Comment here if you face any issues

Comment: Thanks sir. Let me try snd implement it, will update the result ASAP .

Comment: i have added databinding in build.gradle and tried to run the code,  got this error cannot find symbol  ActivityMainBinding binding, what is missing?

Comment: Add viewbinding . If added databinding then declare you whole xml class under layout tag , which might be an added thing to do . So instead of databinding , use viewBinding . In your gradle file , where you have declare dataBinding replace it with viewBinding

Comment: i have successfully added viewbinding, the previous error is gone. However now i have 3 errors on  binding.img_two.setImageURI(result.get(1));                         binding.img_three.setImageURI(result.get(2));                         binding.img_four.setImageURI(result.get(3)); ie. Cannot resolve symbol 'img_two', 'img_three','img_four'........ the first img is working without error; i have checked xml file, all imageview id is  'img_two', 'img_three','img_four', pls assit and i think i'm 50% done now,

Comment: i think have fixed the error with these names:  binding.img.setImageURI(result.get(0));                        binding.imgTwo.setImageURI(result.get(1));                       binding.imgThree.setImageURI(result.get(2));                        binding.imgFour.setImageURI(result.get(3)); No more error now, but when i run the code the button ID 'browse' to select images there is no response. what else is missing?

Comment: If you find FloatingAction button error "
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'"add this to your build.gradle file

Comment: I have updated the answer . Implement the same layout with same naming of imageButton . If you want to you can change the size of the imageview as much as you want

Comment: thanks for your support. i tried ur steps unfortunately still not working. I also copied ur code and start with a new empty actiivty to test it, when i click the floating button it did open the recent folder and when i click images the app crash and forced to stop.

Comment: For me it is working completely fine . What does the crash say ? Something wrong you are doing for sure , it wont crash I have tried running this code several times and have got the right output without crash

Comment: This is the erro code: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at mynj.xyz.viewbinding_4images.MainActivity$1.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:31)
        at mynj.xyz.viewbinding_4images.MainActivity$1.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:26)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1.onStateChanged(ActivityResultRegistry.java:148)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)

Comment: How many images did you select , Less than 4 ?

Comment: i tried to select one first, but it crash. i dont see can select mutiple images; no option to select more than one image

Comment: This is a null exception . Because you are getting values beyond first position from the arraylist but passing only one value

Comment: To select more than one image , press and hold on the image , then click the rest images you want to select

Comment: In my previous code, i got this  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); with this can select multiple images option.

Comment: Yeah you can select multiple images , when recent folder opens , press hold for longer time on an image then you can select multiple images

Comment: I am posting a demo wait

Comment: sir, yes you are  right, i must press and hold images then can select all of them, sorry for my mistake. your code is working! would like to know how to handle if someone only seelct 1 image and the app crash.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no method in java to do so , Either you give option to get multiple images or single images four times . In kotlin , you have abundant ways  to do this job

Comment: ok noted. thank you very much for your guidance and i accepted your answer.

Comment: Happy it helped

Comment: I got one more question, after implemented your code in my project, other buttons in xml are not working, when i click other buttons there are no response, any idea what went wrong?

Comment: What does those buttons do ? Should not happen any issue with those .

Comment: i have figured it out, other button got to add 'binding' before onclick then it got response

Comment: On my onActivityResult, i need to do this to encodeBitmapImage(bitmap) and upload the 4 images to mysql, now the upload button got no response, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The comment section is getting to big . I suggest you to create a new question for the same . Also quick advice , you cannot and should never upload bitmap to database . You should save the image locally and upload it's uri to database . Also if the database is local instead of using sqlite use room database